# How to find the minimum covariant type for best fit between two types?

Tags: c#, types, covariance, contravariance

There's `IsAssignableFrom` method returns a boolean value indicates if one type is assignable from another type.

How can we not only test if they are assignable **from** or **to** each other, but also know the **minimum covariant** type for best fit?

Consider the following example(C# 4.0)

- Code

  ```
  // method body of Func is irrelevant, use default() instead
  Func<char[]> x = default(Func<char[]>);
  Func<int[]> y = default(Func<int[]>);

  Func<Array> f = default(Func<Array>);
  Func<IList> g = default(Func<IList>);

  g=x;
  g=y;

  y=x; // won't compile
  x=y; // won't compile

  // following two are okay; Array is the type for the covariance
  f=x; // Array > char[] -> Func<Array> > Func<char[]> 
  f=y; // Array > int[] -> Func<Array> > Func<int[]> 

  // following two are okay; IList is the interface for the covariance
  g=x;
  g=y;
  ```

In the example above, what to find is the type between `char[]` and `int[]`.

Comment: @DWright: Please let me know if it was still not fine, thank you very much.

Comment: Better. But what does "most possible" mean?  The largest number of combinations?

Comment: Now I'm understanding better.  I'm wondering if the title could reflect that better.  Perhaps: "What all the ways of assigning types to each other?", but that doesn't cover everything you are talking about.  But a title like that conveys better what you are investigating.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

update:

It turns out `FindInterfaceWith` can be simplified and to build a flatten type hierarchy becomes redundant as the base classes are not necessarily involved, as long as we take the type itself into account when it is an interface; so I've added an extension method `GetInterfaces(bool)`. Since we can sort the interaces by the rules of coverage, the sorted intersection of interfaces are the candidates. If all of them are equally good, I said none of them is considered the best one. If it's not the case, then the best one must cover one of the others; and because they are sorted, this kind of relationship should exists in the right most two interfaces in the array to denote that there is a best interface in common which is the most specific.

---

The code can be simplified by using `Linq`; but in my scenario, I should reduce the requirement of references and namespaces as possible ..

- **Code**

  ```
  using System;

  public static class TypeExtensions {
      static int CountOverlapped<T>(T[] ax, T[] ay) {
          return IntersectPreserveOrder(ay, ax).Length;
      }

      static int CountOccurrence(Type[] ax, Type ty) {
          var a = Array.FindAll(ax, x => Array.Exists(x.GetInterfaces(), tx => tx.Equals(ty)));
          return a.Length;
      }

      static Comparison<Type> GetCoverageComparison(Type[] az) {
          return (tx, ty) => {
              int overlapped, occurrence;
              var ay = ty.GetInterfaces();
              var ax = tx.GetInterfaces();

              if(0!=(overlapped=CountOverlapped(az, ax).CompareTo(CountOverlapped(az, ay)))) {
                  return overlapped;
              }

              if(0!=(occurrence=CountOccurrence(az, tx).CompareTo(CountOccurrence(az, ty)))) {
                  return occurrence;
              }

              return 0;
          };
      }

      static T[] IntersectPreserveOrder<T>(T[] ax, T[] ay) {
          return Array.FindAll(ax, x => Array.FindIndex(ay, y => y.Equals(x))>=0);
      }

      /*
      static T[] SubtractPreserveOrder<T>(T[] ax, T[] ay) {
          return Array.FindAll(ax, x => Array.FindIndex(ay, y => y.Equals(x))<0);
      }

      static Type[] GetTypesArray(Type typeNode) {
          if(null==typeNode) {
              return Type.EmptyTypes;
          }

          var baseArray = GetTypesArray(typeNode.BaseType);
          var interfaces = SubtractPreserveOrder(typeNode.GetInterfaces(), baseArray);
          var index = interfaces.Length+baseArray.Length;
          var typeArray = new Type[1+index];
          typeArray[index]=typeNode;
          Array.Sort(interfaces, GetCoverageComparison(interfaces));
          Array.Copy(interfaces, 0, typeArray, index-interfaces.Length, interfaces.Length);
          Array.Copy(baseArray, typeArray, baseArray.Length);
          return typeArray;
      }
      */

      public static Type[] GetInterfaces(this Type x, bool includeThis) {
          var a = x.GetInterfaces();

          if(includeThis&&x.IsInterface) {
              Array.Resize(ref a, 1+a.Length);
              a[a.Length-1]=x;
          }

          return a;
      }

      public static Type FindInterfaceWith(this Type type1, Type type2) {
          var ay = type2.GetInterfaces(true);
          var ax = type1.GetInterfaces(true);
          var types = IntersectPreserveOrder(ax, ay);

          if(types.Length<1) {
              return null;
          }

          Array.Sort(types, GetCoverageComparison(types));
          var type3 = types[types.Length-1];

          if(types.Length<2) {
              return type3;
          }

          var type4 = types[types.Length-2];
          return Array.Exists(type3.GetInterfaces(), x => x.Equals(type4)) ? type3 : null;
      }

      public static Type FindBaseClassWith(this Type type1, Type type2) {
          if(null==type1) {
              return type2;
          }

          if(null==type2) {
              return type1;
          }

          for(var type4 = type2; null!=type4; type4=type4.BaseType) {
              for(var type3 = type1; null!=type3; type3=type3.BaseType) {
                  if(type4==type3) {
                      return type4;
                  }
              }
          }

          return null;
      }

      public static Type FindAssignableWith(this Type type1, Type type2) {
          var baseClass = type2.FindBaseClassWith(type1);

          if(null==baseClass||typeof(object)==baseClass) {
              var @interface = type2.FindInterfaceWith(type1);

              if(null!=@interface) {
                  return @interface;
              }
          }

          return baseClass;
      }
  }
  ```

---

There're two recursive methods; one is `FindInterfaceWith`, the other is an important method `GetTypesArray` as there is already a method named `GetTypeArray` of class `Type` with a different of usage.

It works like the method [Akim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/443366/akim) provided [GetClassHierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107683/how-to-find-the-best-fit-of-common-type-between-two-types/14137582#14137582); but in this version, it builds an array like:

- **output of hierarchy**

  ```
  a[8]=System.String
  a[7]=System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char]
  a[6]=System.Collections.IEnumerable
  a[5]=System.ICloneable
  a[4]=System.IComparable
  a[3]=System.IConvertible
  a[2]=System.IEquatable`1[System.String]
  a[1]=System.IComparable`1[System.String]
  a[0]=System.Object
  ```

As we are aware of they are in a particular order, which is how it makes things work. The array `GetTypesArray` built is in fact a flatten tree. The array is actually in the model as the following:

- **diagram**

  > [image: rFbtV.png]
  >
  > Note the relation of some interfaces implementation such as `IList<int>` implements `ICollection<int>` are not linked with lines in this diagram.

The interfaces in the returning array is sorted by `Array.Sort` with the ordering rules provided by the `GetCoverageComparison`.

There are some things to mention, for example, the possibility of **multiple interfaces implementation** been mentioned not only once in some answers(like [[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107683/how-to-find-the-best-fit-of-common-type-between-two-types/14141496#14141496)]); and I have defined the way to solve them, those are:

- **note**

  1. The [GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) method does not return interfaces in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which interfaces are returned, because that order varies.
  2. Because of recursion, the base classes are always ordered.
  3. If two interfaces have the same coverage, neither of them will be considered eligible.

     Suppose we have these interfaces defined(or classes are just fine):

     ```
     public interface IDelta {
     }

     public interface ICharlie {
     }

     public interface IBravo: IDelta, ICharlie {
     }

     public interface IAlpha: IDelta, ICharlie {
     }
     ```

     then which one is better for assignment of `IAlpha` and `IBravo`? In this case, `FindInterfaceWith` just returns `null`.

In the question [ [How to find the smallest assignable type in two types (duplicate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107683/how-to-find-the-smallest-assignable-type-in-two-types-duplicate) ], I stated:

- **a wrong deduction**

  > If this supposition was correct, then the `FindInterfaceWith` becomes a redundant method; because of the only difference between `FindInterfaceWith` and `FindAssignableWith` is:
  >
  > ***`FindInterfaceWith` returns `null` if there was a best choice of class; while `FindAssignableWith` returns the exact class directly.***

However, now we can look at the method `FindAssignableWith`, it has to call other two methods is based on the original assumption, The paradoxical bug just disappeared magically.

---

About coverage comparison rule of ordering interfaces, in the delegate `GetCoverageComparison`, I use:

- **dual rules**

  1. compare two interfaces in a source interfaces array, with each covering how many others in the source, by calling `CountOverlapped`
  2. If rule 1 does not distinguish them (returns `0`), the secondary ordering is to call `CountOccurrence` to determine which has been inherited more times by others and then comparing

     the two rules are equivalent to the `Linq` query:

     ```
     interfaces=(
         from it in interfaces
         let order1=it.GetInterfaces().Intersect(interfaces).Count()
         let order2=(
             from x in interfaces
             where x.GetInterfaces().Contains(it)
             select x
             ).Count()
         orderby order1, order2
         select it
         ).ToArray();
     ```

     `FindInterfaceWith` will then perform the possibly recursive call, to figure out is this interface sufficient to recognized as the most common interface or just another relation like `IAlpha` and `IBravo`.

And about the method `FindBaseClassWith`, what it returns is different from the original assumption of if any parameter is null then it returns null. It actually returns another argument passed in.

This is related to the question [ [What should the method `FindBaseClassWith` return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360593/what-should-the-method-findbaseclasswith-return) ] about method chaining of `FindBaseClassWith`. In the current implementation, we can call it like:

- **method chaining**

  ```
  var type=
      typeof(int[])
          .FindBaseClassWith(null)
          .FindBaseClassWith(null)
          .FindBaseClassWith(typeof(char[]));
  ```

  It will return `typeof(Array)`; thank to this feature, we can even call

  ```
  var type=
      typeof(String)
          .FindAssignableWith(null)
          .FindAssignableWith(null)
          .FindAssignableWith(typeof(String));
  ```

  What we may not able to do with my implementation is to call `FindInterfaceWith` like above, because of the possibility of relations like `IAlpha` and `IBravo`.

I've had the code tested in some situations by calling `FindAssignableWith` as the examples shown:

- **output of assignable types**

  ```
  (Dictionary`2, Dictionary`2) = Dictionary`2
  (List`1, List`1) = IList
  (Dictionary`2, KeyValuePair`2) = Object
  (IAlpha, IBravo) = <null>
  (IBravo, IAlpha) = <null>
  (ICollection, IList) = ICollection
  (IList, ICollection) = ICollection
  (Char[], Int32[]) = IList
  (Int32[], Char[]) = IList
  (IEnumerable`1, IEnumerable`1) = IEnumerable
  (String, Array) = Object
  (Array, String) = Object
  (Char[], Int32[]) = IList
  (Form, SplitContainer) = ContainerControl
  (SplitContainer, Form) = ContainerControl
  ```

  The `List'1` test appears `IList` is because I tested `typeof(List<int>)` with `typeof(List<String>)`; and the `Dictionary'2` are both `Dictionary<String, String>`. Sorry that I did not do the work to present the exact type names.

Comment: You: _... ``(List`1, List`1) = IList`` ... Sorry about that I did not do the work to present exact type names._ If you have a `System.Type` like `t = typeof(List<int>)`, you get only ``"List`1"`` if you use `t.Name`. If instead you use `t.ToString()`, you get more information: ``"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"``

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Ah, thank you for that. My test code was written in Linq(since many cases), but the return value of `Find X^9 With` methods are possible to return `null`. I did not write a extension method to do the work. And actually, to make the name(with actual `T`) shown without the name of namespace, there're some little more to do.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case would be iterating over the base types of one object and checking them for being assignable with the other type, like this:

- Code

  ```
  public Type GetClosestType(Type a, Type b) {
      var t=a;

      while(a!=null) {
          if(a.IsAssignableFrom(b))
              return a;

          a=a.BaseType;
      }

      return null;
  }
  ```

This will produce `System.Object` for two types which are unrelated, if they are both classes. I'm not sure if this behaviour met your requirement.

For more advanced cases, I'm using a custom extension method called `IsExtendablyAssignableFrom`.

It can handle different numeric types, generics, interfaces, generic parameters, implicit conversions, nullable, boxing/unboxing, and pretty much all the types I have come across with when implementing my own compiler.

I've uploaded the code into a separate github repository [[here](https://github.com/impworks/typetools)], so you could use it in your project.

Comment: The code is pretty huge, especially the numeric-related part. I believe the repository on GitHub is virtually eternal :)

Comment: I've read up the code, and thought `IsExtendablyAssignableFrom` may not meet the requirement, but `MostWideType` seems closely.

Comment: @KenKin, it does not resolve the closest type by itself. I believe you can use `MostWideType` for numerics and the snippet from my original post with `IsExtendablyAssignableFrom` instead of `IsAssignableFrom` for reference types.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at base classes *only*, the problem is trivial and a solution is given by Impworks's answer ("iterating over one object's parents and checking them for being assignable with the other type").

But if you want to include also interfaces, there's no unique solution to the problem, as you note yourself with your `IDelta` and `ICharlie` example. Two or more interfaces can easily be equally "good", so there's no single best solution. One can easily construct arbitrarily complex diagrams (graphs) of interface inheritances, and it's easy to see from such diagrams that there's no well-defined "FindAssignableWith".

Besides, covariance/contravariance in C# are used for variance kinds of ***generic*** types. Let me give an example. Supose we have

```
type1: System.Func<string>
type2: System.Func<Tuple<int>>
```

then of course with base classes, the "FindAssignableWith" could be

```
solutionA: System.MulticastDelegate
```

But the type `Func<out T>` is also *covariant* (`out`) in its type parameter `T`. Therefore, the type

```
solutionB: System.Func<System.Object>
```

is also a solution in the sense that it `IsAssignableFrom` the two given types `type1` and `type2`. But the same could be said of

```
solutionC: System.Func<System.IComparable>
```

which works because both `string` and `Tuple<>` are `IComparable`.

So in the general case, there's no unique solution. So unless you specify precise rules describing what you want, we can't come up with an algorithm that finds your solution.

Comment: @KenKin Covariance is what makes a `Func<object>` "assignable from" a `Func<string>` even if `Func<object>` is not a base class of `Func<string>`. Contravariance is similar, but goes the other way, for example an `IComparer<string>` is "assignable from" an `IComparer<object>`. Read [What's the difference between covariance and assignment compatibility?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx) for more info on this terminology. Also see [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).