# How do you insert a value into an array, preserving order?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array, and I want to add a new value somewhere in the center, but don't know how to do this. Can anyone please make this method for me?

```
void AddValueToArray(String ValueToAdd, String AddAfter, ref String[] theArray) {
    // Make this Value the first value
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(AddAfter)) {
        theArray[0]=ValueToAdd; // WRONG: This replaces the first Val, want to Add a new String 
        return;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<theArray.Length; i++) {
        if(theArray[i]==AddAfter) {
            theArray[i++]=ValueToAdd; // WRONG: Again replaces, want to Add a new String 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody here is going to do your homework...

Comment: I am pretty sure somebody will tbh :)

Comment: Hint: First you need to move all the elements of the array after the add point, increasing the array's size by one.  Then set the value.  Further hints: An array may not be the ideal structure for this.  A `LinkedList` would probably be a lot better.  Or perhaps don't store the values in order but read them in order with `OrderBy` when needed?

Comment: Arrays are not supposed to work like this, why do you need it to be an Array? it seems like a list its what you should use

Comment: LoL, its not homework.  I just thought there would be a smarter way to do this without List<string> = array.ToList(), list.insert(3, string), array = list.ToArray() ...

Comment: .NET already comes with a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) class; is there some reason you can't use it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't add items to an array, it always remains the same size.

To get an array with the item added, you would need to allocate a new array with one more item, and copy all items from the original array to the new array.

This is certainly doable, but not efficient. You should use a `List<string>` instead, which already has an `Insert` metod.

Answer (score 2):

This would work only in some particular case.

```
public static void AddValueToArray(ref String[] theArray, String valueToAdd, String addAfter) {
    var count=theArray.Length;
    Array.Resize(ref theArray, 1+count);
    var index=Array.IndexOf(theArray, addAfter);
    var array=Array.CreateInstance(typeof(String), count-index);
    Array.Copy(theArray, index, array, 0, array.Length);
    ++index;
    Array.Copy(array, 0, theArray, index, array.Length);
    theArray[index]=valueToAdd;
}
```

Here's a sample, but it works with `Type`, you might need to modify the type you need. It is an example of copying array recursively.

- [How to find the minimum covariant type for best fit between two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/evaluate-the-minimum-covariance-type-to-fit-both-of-types)

Answer (score 0):

See how [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) Insert method is implemented

Comment: As `IList` is an interface, it doesn't contain any implementation.