# Convert generic parameter with 'where' type constraint not possible?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class DomainEventSubscriber<T> where T : DomainEvent
{
    public abstract void HandleEvent(T domainEvent);
    public Type SubscribedToEventType() { return typeof(T); }
}
```

And a class which stores the `DomainEventSubscriber` references:

```
public class DomainEventPublisher
{
    private List<DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>> subscribers;

    public void Subscribe<T>(DomainEventSubscriber<T> subscriber)
        where T : DomainEvent
    {
        DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent> eventSubscriber;
        eventSubscriber = (DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>)subscriber;

        if (!this.Publishing)
        {
            this.subscribers.Add(eventSubscriber);
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the `Subscribe` method type is constrained, I cannot convert from `DomainEventSubscriber<T> subscriber` `where T : DomainEvent` to `DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>`:

```
eventSubscriber = (DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>)subscriber;
```

How would I go about performing this conversion, or am I setting myself up for a nasty code smell?

Comment: You need an interface with an <out T> value. Not sure if you can do that here.

Comment: Nevertheless, worth sticking an `out` into `public abstract class DomainEventSubscriber<out T> where T : DomainEvent` to see if it works.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That will _never_ work since `out` and `in` generic type modifiers can only be used with interfaces, _not classes_.

Comment: @Virtlink Fair enough, perhaps he could try making it an interface!

Comment: Your design is flawed. You are trying to entitle yourself to be able to send simple `DomainEvent` instance to `HandleEvent(MyDomainEvent)` method, which will never work. Compiler did a good job by protecting you from doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Covariance

You need an interface with a covariant type parameter `T` to be able to cast it to a base type of `T`. For example, `IEnumerable<out T>` is such an interface. Note the `out` keyword, which means `T` is covariant and can therefore only appear in *output* positions (e.g. as return values and getters). Because of covariance, you can cast an `IEnumerable<Dolphin>` to `IEnumerable<Mammal>`: an enumerable sequence of dolphins is surely also an enumerable sequence of mammals.

#### Contravariance

However, you cannot make `DomainEventSubscriber<T>` an interface `IDomainEventSubscriber<out T>` as `T` then appears in the *input* position of `HandleEvent`. You could make it an interface `IDomainEventSubscriber<in T>`.

Note the `in` keyword, which means `T` is *contravariant* and can only appear in *input* positions (e.g. as method parameters). For example, `IEqualityComparer<in T>` is such an interface. Because of contravariance, you can cast an `IEqualityComparer<Mammal>` to `IEqualityComparer<Dolphin>`: if it can compare mammals, then surely it can compare dolphins as they are mammals.

But this also does not solve your problem since you can cast a contravariant type parameter only to a *more* derived type, and you want to cast it to base type.

---

#### Solution

I advise you to create a non-generic `IDomainEventSubscriber` interface and derive your current class from that:

```
public interface IDomainEventSubscriber
{
    void HandleEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent);
    Type SubscribedToEventType();
}

public abstract class DomainEventSubscriber<T> : IDomainEventSubscriber
    where T : DomainEvent
{
    void IDomainEventSubscriber.HandleEvent(DomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        if (domainEvent.GetType() != SubscribedToEventType())
            throw new ArgumentException("domainEvent");

        HandleEvent((T)domainEvent);
    }

    public abstract void HandleEvent(T domainEvent);

    public Type SubscribedToEventType() { return typeof(T); }
}
```

And then use the `IDomainEventSubscriber` internally instead of `DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>`:

```
public class DomainEventPublisher
{
    private List<IDomainEventSubscriber> subscribers;

    public void Subscribe<T>(DomainEventSubscriber<T> subscriber)
        where T : DomainEvent
    {
        if (!this.Publishing)
        {
            this.subscribers.Add(eventSubscriber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There're good answers for the solution, here I'm point out a little bit for the simple reason why you cannot make it work.

The generic base classes can be inherited, however, with different type parameters are just different classes. Consider `List<int>` and `List<String>`. Although they both have the generic definition of `` List`1 ``, but they take different type parameter; none of them are the base class of the other. What your method does, would be like the following:

```
public void Subscribe<T>(List<T> subscriber) where T: struct {
    var eventSubscriber=(List<int>)subscriber;

    // ... 
}
```

this would not compile, and even you change declaration for compile-able as:

```
public void Subscribe<T>(List<T> subscriber) where T: struct {
    var eventSubscriber=(List<int>)(subscriber as object);

    // ... 
}
```

and pass an instance of `List<byte>` would be invalid cast at runtime.

Thus even you've specified the constraints, it just doesn't work.

Beside the existing answers, an alternative way is define a base class(can also be abstract) for the generic class, and make your `Subscribe` take the base class. However, this would require that you move the abstract method to the base class and change the method signature as a generic method; so it might not be applicable for you.

For knowing the type variance, and assignment ability, you might want to have a look of my Q&A style question:

[How to find the minimum covariant type for best fit between two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-the-minimum-covariant-type-for-best-fit-between-two-types)

You can use it to get some information about the types, for debugging, and I wish that would be helpful to you for understanding about types.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different take using an interface:

```
public class DomainEvent
{
}

// The 'in' isn't actually needed to make this work, but it can be added anyway:

public interface IDomainEventSubscriber<in T> where T: DomainEvent
{
    void HandleEvent(T domainEvent);
    Type SubscribedToEventType();
}

public abstract class DomainEventSubscriber<T>: IDomainEventSubscriber<T> where T: DomainEvent
{
    public abstract void HandleEvent(T domainEvent);
    public Type SubscribedToEventType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}

public class DomainEventPublisher
{
    private List<DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>> subscribers;

    public void Subscribe<T>(IDomainEventSubscriber<T> subscriber)
        where T: DomainEvent
    {
        DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent> eventSubscriber;
        eventSubscriber = (DomainEventSubscriber<DomainEvent>)subscriber;

        if (!this.Publishing)
        {
            this.subscribers.Add(eventSubscriber);
        }
    }
}
```