# Why can't I make a Backbone.Collection of Backbone.Views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

*TLDR, question at the bottom. I solved my issue, but after typing all this up, still thought I'd throw out the underlying question*

**For anyone looking into this error, here's the description/solution:**

I'm getting an error when trying to add a View to a Collection:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_validate'
```

**I solved my problem:**

I was defining my collection to use a Model that was really a View:

```
ViewCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: MyView });
```

MyView was an instance of `Backbone.View`, not a model, duh.

### **Conceptual Question:**

Is it OK to use a `Backbone.Collection` instead of an `array` or `object`, to store things, like a `Backbone.Collection` of `Backbone.Views`, or any generic array of objects?  If my model has multiple views, is it common to store them like so:

```
model
    collectionOfViews
        view
        view
        view
```

Comment: You can make your posts in Q&A style, such as what I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-the-minimum-covariant-type-for-best-fit-between-two-types/14472104#14472104

Comment: Oh, yes, please don't mix Question and Solution. It's even possible, if you judge so, to change the accepted answer for your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the point of a collection is to query a set of models. That's its entire reason for existence, to filter down a set of data in your model layer. It makes *no sense* to query views.

The very first sentence in the Backbone documentation on `Collection`:

> Collections are ordered sets of models.

Collection was never intended to be a replacement for array, it's not *supposed* to wrap a set of arbitrary objects. It wasn't designed or intended or tested to be used in the way you're trying to use it.

Comment: How about as simply a mechanism to make underscore's collection functions object oriented?  `_.invoke(collection, 'method')` vs `collection.invoke('method')`

Comment: @MikeLewis Use `_.method(array)` if you want to apply some underscore method to an arbitrary array of views.

Comment: A) So what? B) if you want it to by OO, use `_(my_array).method` instead of `_.method(my_array)`.

Comment: In my initial comment, it seems like a very good idea to have a generic collection class, that you can use instead of a generic array, for quicker access to those functions.  I realize what you're saying would work equally, it just would feel better to me to have it attached to the `collection`, like the `Backbone.Collection`

Comment: Then, see B) `_(my_array).method`. `_(my_array)` will return an object that you can invoke arbitrary underscore methods on.

Comment: So, rather than `model.views = new ViewCollection();` I could use `model.views = _([]);`, and then say `model.views.add(view)`?  Or `model.views.invoke('methodName')`?

Comment: You *could*, but why are you trying to do this in the first place? Why do you need a container for your views which is more complex than a simple array?

Comment: 1) Its not JUST for views, what if I have an array of some other modules.  2) Its just easier to have all the underscore functions directly attached to the collection, rather than have to write it backwards, starting with `_(`.  A minor difference, but organizationally, it seems to make more sense.  This is what `Backbone.Collection` does, I'm just surprised there's no generic version.

Comment: I'm disappointed this is the case, but thank you for your help.  I'll try asking a new question with this new insight.