# Underscore.js - OO: Get item at index? Is there a better JS library to do this?

Tags: underscore.js, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm trying to use underscore in an OO way:

```
var myCollection = _([]);
myCollection.push('one');
myCollection.push('two');
myCollection.push('three');
```

**How do I get the item at a numeric index?  I'm sure I'm missing something, other than using `myCollection.toArray()[1]`.  There's no `myCollection.get(1)`?**

Also, **if I use `myCollection.push('something')`, it returns an `array`, which isn't chainable.**  I'm really confused why there isn't something out there like this already.

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695237/why-cant-i-use-backbone-collection-as-a-generic-collection-is-there-an-impleme), I'm trying to use underscore in an OO way, and not have to rewrap the array/object every time.  After some of these challenges, it appears its not really meant to be used this way?

So now I'm wondering, **is there a better library that has a generic, chainable, OOP, collection wrapper?**

Comment: Why not just use a "dumb Array" here? Anyway, to answer the last question: jQuery (mostly, the results of `$(..)` is a collection and `x[0]` is the same as `x.get(0)`).

Comment: I'd really like an object I can add methods to...

Comment: Plus, I'd like to attach the underscore helper functions to the collection

Comment: I have messed around with using jQuery for non-dom collections.  It feels too heavy for a simple collection.  What I'd really like is something with `.extend` like Backbone's classes.

Comment: If you're committed to Underscore, maybe write your own Backbone-like proxies?  http://jsfiddle.net/7CRGQ/4/  Otherwise, maybe Lodash would be more to your taste?  It seems to chain in the case you mentioned.  (I'm sure there are other OO-type JS libraries, too -- I don't have broad knowledge in this area.)

Comment: Underscore is meant to be used in a functional way, not as an object-orietated wrapper. Why would you need that?

Comment: `.push` does never return an array, it does return the length of the array after the element(s) are appended to it.

Comment: If you want something chainable, use [chaining with `_.chain()`](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) instead of the simple wrapper utility `_()`

Comment: @Bergi: Underscore is meant to be used both ways, hence the `_.f` and `_().f` interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need that method to access single elements directly on a wrapped array (or object), you can implement it yourself easily using [`_.mixin`](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin):

```
_.mixin({
    get: function(obj, key) { // works on arrays as well
         return obj[key];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Underscore like this, you can simply add necessary method yourself to `_.prototype`:

```
// probably name it something other then get
_.prototype.get = function(i) {
    return this.toArray()[i];
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `toArray` at all?

Comment: You should use `_.mixin` to extend `_` so that your additions behave the same was as the rest of Underscore.