# Compare objects and determine common type

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, types

Short Version: Are the comments in the code correct? I think they are incorrect and should be reversed.

```
public Type GetTestClass(Object left, Object right)
{
    if (left == null || right == null) return null;

    Type leftClass = left.GetType();
    Type rightClass = right.GetType();
    Type testClass;
    if (leftClass.IsInstanceOfType(right))
    {
        testClass = leftClass;
        if (!rightClass.IsInstanceOfType(left))
        {
            // rightClass is a subclass of leftClass
            testClass = rightClass;
        }
    }
    else if (rightClass.IsInstanceOfType(left))
    {
        testClass = rightClass;
        if (!leftClass.IsInstanceOfType(right))
        {
            // leftClass is a subclass of rightClass
            testClass = leftClass;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The two classes are not related.
        testClass = null;
    }

return testClass;
}
```

I came across this code in a code-base that I am working on and I think the comments are incorrect. I believe that the comments `//rightClass is a subclass of leftClass` and `//leftClass is a subclass of rightClass` are incorrect. For example, if `leftClass` is of type `Object` and `rightClass` is of type `MyClass` (which inherits from Object) then this is the how I believe the code works...

1. `Object` is an instance of `MyClass` is FALSE
2. `MyClass` is an instance of `Object` is TRUE
3. `testClass` is set to `MyClass`
4. NOT (`Object` is an instance of `MyClass` is FALSE) is TRUE
5. `testClass` is set to `Object`
6. `testClass` is returned which == `Object`

I believe this is the correct functionality... ultimately the code is attempting to return the super-most class (you could also say the common Base class) of the two classes, or null if they are not related.  Using the example above (steps 1-5) isn't it actually correct to say that the leftClass is a SUPER class of rightClass... or, reversed, the rightClass is a SUBCLASS of leftClass?

Comment: Please tell me you are going to slap an [Obsolete("DO NOT USE")] on that!

Comment: I've added code that I had left out. There is more going on in the code than what I've put up here... but it doesn't apply to my question. I really do appreciate the comments & code below so far... but I think my question hasn't been answered yet which is: Is my understanding of the code correct and the comments are incorrect?

Comment: @Steve, `leftClass.IsInstanceOfType(right)` means that "the right is a left".  `rightClass.IsInstanceOfType(left)` means that "the left is a right".  If the right is a left, but the left is not a right, then the left must be the super class, and the right must be the subclass.  This is equivalent to the first case, where you have the comment "rightClass is a subclass of leftClass".

Comment: So, it seems like the comments' intentions are actually accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leftClass.IsInstanceOfType(right)` means that "the right is a left". `rightClass.IsInstanceOfType(left)` means that "the left is a right".

If the right is a left, but the left is not a right, then the left must be the super class, and the right must be the subclass. This is equivalent to the first case, where you have the comment "rightClass is a subclass of leftClass". So, it seems like the comments' intentions are actually accurate.

However, I see a few problems with the method.  The comments are the least of your worries.

1. It will throw `NullReferenceException` if either parameter is null.
2. It makes unnecessary calls to `GetType()`, because the actual source code for `IsInstanceOfType` looks like this:

   ```
   public virtual bool IsInstanceOfType(object o)
   {
       if (o == null)
       {
           return false;
       }
       return this.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType());
   }
   ```

   You should take @p.s.w.g.'s advice and use `IsAssignableFrom`, and possibly consider refactoring the signature compare two Types instead of two Objects.
3. Any two concrete types will always have at least a common base type of `System.Object`.  Returning null is not an acceptable result here.
4. It doesn't handle cases where one type is not linearly derived from the other type, but both still have a common base class that is more derived than `System.Object`.  For example,

   ```
   public class Base { }

   public class A : Base { }

   public class B : Base { }
   ```

   Your method would say that `A` and `B` are unrelated and return null, where the correct "common base" would be `Base`.

I would look at the implementation provided at [Easiest way to get a common base class from a collection of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353430/easiest-way-to-get-a-common-base-class-from-a-collection-of-types), which still is not perfect, but is better than the one you posted.

### Update : Working code

I decided not to be stingy and I've posted the method that I use for this purpose below.  Good luck.

```
    /// <summary> Finds the most derived common base class of all the provided types, or System.Object if there is no common base class  </summary>
    public static Type CommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(types,null)) return typeof(object);
        types = types.Where(x => !ReferenceEquals(x,null)).Distinct().ToArray();
        switch (types.Length)
        {
            case 0: return typeof(object);
            case 1: return types[0].IsInterface ? typeof(object): types[0];
            default:
                IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Type>> hierarchies = types.Select(ClassHierarchy).OrderBy(x => x.Count());
                Queue<Type> smallest = new Queue<Type>(hierarchies.First().Reverse());
                hierarchies = hierarchies.Skip(1);
                do
                {
                    int maxPossible = smallest.Count;
                    hierarchies = hierarchies.Select(each => each.Take(maxPossible));
                    Type candidate = smallest.Dequeue();
                    if (hierarchies.All(each => each.Last() == candidate))
                        return candidate;
                } while (smallest.Count > 1);
                return typeof(object);
        }
    }


    ///<summary>Gets the class hierarchy of the provided type, in order of derivation, e.g. : (System.Object,CustomBaseType,CustomConcreteType,...), or the singleton of System.Object type if the provided type is an interface or null </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> ClassHierarchy(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null || type.IsInterface) type = typeof(object);
        var stack = new Stack<Type>();
        do
        {
            stack.Push(type);
            type = type.BaseType;
        } while (type != null);
        return stack;

    }
```

Comment: I have the feeling your example code is a little bloated for the purpuse... In what is the result different from my example code?

Comment: @MartinMulder, (1) Our methods handle interfaces differently.  (2) Your code doesn't handle the cases I described in point #4 in my answer

Comment: @MartinMulder, (3) Your operation is binary.  Mine is n-ary.  (which may very well be an example of "bloat for the purpose", but it does produce a more generic, reusable method)

Comment: My code DOES handle Point #4. My function is very easily converted into more than two type parameters. I will work on the interfaces :)

Comment: In your example, if there is ANY interface, your code will return `object`. I think that is to easy. `ICollection<int>` and `IList<int>` should return `ICollection<int>`. And `List<int>` plus `IEnumerable<int>` should return `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @MartinMulder, I addressed this in a comment on your answer.  Read the difference in the method names.  `IEnumerable<int>` is not a "class", and a method that promises a "base class" should not return an interface as a value.

Comment: @MartinMulder, furthermore, if we were to follow your logic, it would be impossible to return a correct result in cases where two types share multiple common disjoints interfaces, which is allowed since .NET supports a single type implementing multiple interfaces from disjoint hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Update to reflect changes to handle interface types.
**EDIT**: Extra function added to support more than 2 types.

First of all: A type cannot be an instance of another type (except when we are talking about an instance of type `Type`.) Only an object can be an instance of a type.

Types can be subtypes of each other (using `IsSubType`). Types can be assignable to another type (using `IsAssignableFrom`).

To find a common type, try this example. This will always produce a common type (object):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the most common type of two types.
    /// If no common type can be found, null is returned.
    /// </summary>
    static public Type GetCommonBaseClass(Type a, Type b)
    {
        if ((a == null) || (b ==null))
            return null;
        if (a.IsInterface || b.IsInterface)
            return null;
        if (a.IsAssignableFrom(b))
            return a;
        while (true)
        {
            if (b.IsAssignableFrom(a))
                return b;
            b = b.BaseType;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the most common type of one or more types.
    /// If no common type can be found, null is returned.
    /// </summary>
    static public Type GetCommonBaseClass(params Type[] types)
    {
        if ((types == null) || (types.Length == 0))
            return null;
        Type type = types[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            type = GetCommonBaseClass(type, types[i]);
        return type;
    }
```

And called from your function:

```
public Type GetTestClass(Object left, Object right)
{
     return GetCommonBaseClass(left.GetType(), right.GetType());
}
```

Comment: This will not "always produce a common type".  Try using disjoint interfaces.

Comment: What is a "disjoint" interfaces? Can you give me an example?

Comment: In this context, two disjoint interfaces are two interfaces such that neither inherits the other.  E.g. `IComparable` and `IEnumerable` are disjoint, whereas `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` are not.  Get it?

Comment: I understand. Thank you. My (updated) code produces resp. `null` and `IEnumerable`. Your code produces resp. `object` and `object`.

Comment: I want to point out that we made a different design decision with respect to how we handle interfaces and null parameters.  You chose to return null and I chose to return `typeof(object)`.  I'm not saying one way is more right, but I'll explain my reasoning: In terms of type inheritance, any concrete object will be derived from `System.Object`, so returning `System.Object` can be seen as an implementation of the [Null Object Pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NullObject.aspx).  The benefit of this is that client code doesn't need to do null checks on the result to avoid errors and will

Comment: instead use the "practical" base class (`System.Object`).  In response to your comparison of the results for the interface comparisons, I am aware of this discrepancy.  However, the reason I return `Object` instead of `IEnumerable` for the comparison between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` should be evident if you read the method names.  Mine is `CommonBaseClass`, where as yours is `GetCommonType`.  Returning `IEnumerable` as a "base class" would be inappropriate, whereas it is acceptable to return it as a "type".  (b/c `IEnumerable` is not a class)

Comment: Okay... to come back at my first comment. If I would replace in my 'return null' with 'return typeof(object)', and if I would check for interface types and return `object`, our function would produce exactly the same. Once again my question: is your example code not be a little bit bloated compared to mine?

Comment: Martin, I think at this point we are discussing coding style.  I feel like my code is more readable than yours, but I acknowledge that it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I adjusted my code. I think you have a good point that when you are talking about not being able to return a common interface when multiple interfaces could be implemented. So now the code will always return `null` (in your case `object`) if an interface type is involved. So in essense (besides the `null` vs `object`) or two code examples do exactly the same, right?

Comment: More readable... okay... so far I felt this was a serious discussion, but you cannot seriously mean that all that 2 loops, 4 if's, 9 LINQ statements, 1 switch/case, 1 queue, 1 enumerable of enumerables and +/-1300 bytes of code is more readable than just 2 loops + 5 if's and +/-600 bytes of code?

Comment: Martin, I'm sure you can find plenty of programmers who would agree with you, but I honestly don't think length corresponds to readability.  If "concise" meant "readable", then Haskell would be easy to learn (it's not).  To me, using a queue and the LINQ methods, communicates semantic meaning that makes the method easier to understand.  As I said, I acknowledge this is a matter of personal opinion/preference.  On a side note, I'm not 100% certain that we will always get the same results, and we'd have to run some tests to be sure.

Comment: I also think the fact that you had to rewrite your method several times (all making it more conformant with the one I initially presented) indicates that my approach may have been thought out a little bit more, which I believe is a consequence of my focus on semantics in my coding **style**.  I am not saying this to be rude, but only to point out that there is a reason I write code the way I do, and that it may be worthwhile to at least consider the validity of my methodology prior to dismissing it as "bloated".

Comment: You last comment is below the belt. I modified my code simply to: (1) support more than 2 parameters, and (2) to support interfaces, which it already did in the first place. I only returned null (or an exception, I do not know anymore), modified it to return interface types and changed it back to not support interface types because you made a valid point about multiple interfaces.

Comment: As I said, it is not my intention to be rude or disrespectful in any way.  All I'm saying is that we clearly have different ways of approaching the problem, and I think it's fair to show mutual respect for either approach.  If it makes you feel any better, then I have no problem admitting that there is no question about the fact that your method can be represented with fewer characters than mine.